# Chrome App Manifest Not Allowing My URL'S

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

My manifest has the following permissions line:

`"permissions": ["https://api.vineapp.com/*", "storage", "webRequest",` `"http://platform.vine.co/*", "background","*://davine.co/*", "notifications"]`

I've started uploading and publishing my app to the Chrome Web Store but it came back with the following error,

```
An error occurred: Failed to process your item.

The field permissions.https://api.vineapp.com/* is not allowed in manifest.
The field permissions.http://platform.vine.co/* is not allowed in manifest.
The field permissions.*://davine.co/* is not allowed in manifest.
```

But it is clearly stated in the Chrome App docs that any domains you plan on making ajax/xhr requests to should be stated in the permissions on the manifest. I tried removing them from my manifest and uploading again, which it went through, but I got tons of CORS errors and my app is disallowed from making requests.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried using wildcards, but it should work removing the trailing asterisk as the documentation says here: [Referencing External Resources](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external.html#external)

Also the url with a wildcard in the protocol will not be kosher, try like this instead:

```
"permissions": ["https://api.vineapp.com/", "storage", "webRequest",
"http://platform.vine.co/", "background","http://davine.co/", "https://davine.co/",
"notifications"]
```

And add any other than http or https to the list.

Comment: Note that "Referencing External Resources" seems inconsistent with the specification for [match patterns](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/match_patterns.html) -- I suspect this is a recent change, and Google has not yet corrected their inconsistent documentation. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using wildcard like this pattern?

```
"permissions": ["https://api.vineapp.com*", "storage", "webRequest",
      "http://platform.vine.co*", "background","*://davine.co*", "notifications"]
```